# How do you enable LIMIT for DELETE in SQLite?

Tags: sqlite, limit, sql-delete

Using PHP, I have a simple database that may store multiple items with the same content. I want to delete the first occurrence of an instance when I use DELETE.

How do you enable LIMIT for DELETE in SQLite using PHP?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You cannot enable these options from within PHP, **you need to compile SQLite yourself** in order to enable these options. Importantly, you need to download the **full version, not the amalgamation** source release from [SQLite download page](http://sqlite.org/download.html).

If you're on Unix, get the `sqlite-3.6.20.tar.gz` tarball and download it. Then:

```
tar xzf sqlite-3.6.20.tar.gz
cd sqlite-3.6.20
export CFLAGS='-DSQLITE_ENABLE_UPDATE_DELETE_LIMIT=1'
./configure
make
```

Then you'll have the `sqlite3` command-line utility and the library files in the `.libs` subdirectory.

Comment: I know you didn't do this, but why was my question locked?

Comment: I found it didn't work, the version I use is 3.7.6.2.
Any other ideas?

Comment: These days you can pass the `--enable-update-limit` option to `./configure` instead of touching cflags. (Still have to define `SQLITE_ENABLE_UPDATE_DELETE_LIMIT` when using the created `sqlite3.c` amalgamation in a separate project, of course)

Comment: Adding a comment that on some hosting plans, especially cPanel ones, I've noticed that DELETE and UPDATE do not support LIMIT, to my shock.

Answer (score 29):

You can use limit with select and you can combine select and delete like:

```
DELETE FROM Foo
WHERE someColumn in
(
  SELECT someColumn FROM FOO WHERE SomeCondition LIMIT 200
)
```

Comment: Clever trick. One more thing: it is safer to use PK column for `someColumn`.

Comment: Not really the same.  The number of rows matched may be more than 200.

Comment: for me it did not work until I replaced `IN` with `=`.

Answer (score 18):

```
DELETE FROM table WHERE rowid = (SELECT rowid FROM table WHERE condition LIMIT 1 )
```

Comment: Or:
DELETE FROM table WHERE rowid IN (SELECT rowid FROM table WHERE condition LIMIT amount_of_rows)

Comment: @LionKing No using `IN` did not work, worked only with `=`

Comment: @MehdiRezzagHebla  using the IN form works as expected for me directly in sqlite3.  I know this is old comment, but want to clarify it does work.

Answer (score 3):

From [here](http://sqlite.org/compile.html#enable_update_delete_limit),  it seems that you have to compile the SQLite source code using

```
#define SQLITE_ENABLE_UPDATE_DELETE_LIMIT
```

in order to enable it.

Comment: Whoops, I should have noted that I'm doing this with php.