# PHP5 SQLite3 recompile for UPDATE, DELETE LIMIT

Tags: php, linux, sqlite, apache2

I need recompile SQLite3 with CFLAG:

```
SQLITE_ENABLE_UPDATE_DELETE_LIMIT
```

as is written in [How do you enable LIMIT for DELETE in SQLite?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1824490/how-do-you-enable-limit-for-delete-in-sqlite):

```
tar xzf sqlite-3.6.20.tar.gz
cd sqlite-3.6.20
export CFLAGS='-DSQLITE_ENABLE_UPDATE_DELETE_LIMIT=1'
./configure
make
```

compilation were done with no errors.

but PHP5 still ends with:

```
Warning: SQLite3::query() [sqlite3.query]: near "LIMIT": syntax error in /var/www/xxx.php on line 987
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a step missing from this process,

```
make install
```

This should come after make. This will install the library to the right place on your system.