# Workaround for DELETE ... LIMIT clause (SQL)

Tags: sql, sqlite

I am working on a database query abstraction layer that supports SQLite.

Unfortunately, SQLite does not support the `LIMIT` clause in DELETE (and UPDATE etc.) queries - except if compiled with a special flag in more recent versions.

So is there any workaround that I could implement so that that query type can still be supported?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you enable LIMIT for DELETE in SQLite?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1824490/how-do-you-enable-limit-for-delete-in-sqlite)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although LIMIT is not innately supported in your build of SQLite you may be able to reproduce the behavior by implementing a method that uses a LIMIT select in a subquery to identify the rows that will be updated or deleted. You should be aware that this will cause some performance degradation over using a LIMIT enabled SQLite build but if you need the functionality this would seem like a viable option.

If you are working with a large set of data or find that the performance hit from trying this is too severe the other option would be to use a LIMIT select to populate a temp table and then join against that table as part of your delete or update.

Comment: I like this answer. :)
One more thing, though: there's no way of knowing the primary key column for me based on the data I get in the query objects - is there any way around that?

Comment: @Franz - Well that's something of a unique situation. If you're receiving such generic data that you can't tell what the PK is for the schema you're targeting then you could be stuck. The only thing I can think of is that if you're given a complete list of the attributes for a tuple you could attempt a WHERE and specify every attribute you have. Of course this would only work if the table is guaranteed to have unique tuples.

Comment: I think I'll just go with not supporting DELETE ... LIMIT clauses. Gah, SQLite pisses me off!