# How to delete range of items from database with gorm

Tags: go, go-gorm

Every time I run a gorm query to delete a range of rows from a table I get the following error.

```
(/home/gregf/code/go/src/github.com/gregf/gormtest/main.go:39)
[2015-06-24 18:55:56]  [0.34ms]  SELECT  id FROM "podcasts"

(/home/gregf/code/go/src/github.com/gregf/gormtest/main.go:50)
[2015-06-24 18:55:56]  near "LIMIT": syntax error

(/home/gregf/code/go/src/github.com/gregf/gormtest/main.go:50)
[2015-06-24 18:55:56]  [0.82ms]  DELETE FROM "episodes"  WHERE (podcast_id = '1') LIMIT 4 OFFSET 2
2015/06/24 18:55:56 &{{0 0   false } near "LIMIT": syntax error 0 <nil> 0xc20802c280 0xc20802c140 0xc20802f900 2 <nil> <nil> false  map[gorm:started_transaction0xc2080380c00xc20805a1c0:true] map[]}
```

Running the query in sqlite3 directly returns just fine

```
DELETE FROM "episodes"  WHERE (podcast_id = '1') LIMIT 4 OFFSET 2;
Run Time: real 0.000 user 0.000000 sys 0.000000
```

Example code

```
package main

import (
    "log"

    "github.com/jinzhu/gorm"
    _ "github.com/mattn/go-sqlite3"
)

type Podcast struct {
    Id       int
    Title    string
    RssUrl   string `sql:"unique_index"`
    Episodes []Episode
}

type Episode struct {
    Id         int
    PodcastID  int
    Title      string
    Url        string `sql:"unique_index"`
    Downloaded bool
    Guid       string `sql:"unique_index"`
}

func main() {
    db, err := gorm.Open("sqlite3", "cache.db")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    db.LogMode(true)

    db.CreateTable(&Podcast{})
    db.CreateTable(&Episode{})

    rows, err := db.Table("podcasts").Select("id").Rows()
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    for rows.Next() {
        var podcastId int
        rows.Scan(&podcastId)
        err := db.Table("episodes").Where("podcast_id = ?", podcastId).
            Limit(4).
            Offset(2).
            Delete(Episode{})

        if err != nil {
            log.Printf("%s\n", err)
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like it's a problem of sqlite3 driver.
Please check this thread: [How do you enable LIMIT for DELETE in SQLite?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1824490/how-do-you-enable-limit-for-delete-in-sqlite)

You need to pass flag SQLITE_ENABLE_UPDATE_DELETE_LIMIT to this driver somehow. Unfortunately, I have no idea how, because the driver uses "amalgamation" of SQLite source code and documentation says that you cannot use SQLITE_ENABLE_UPDATE_DELETE_LIMIT with it (https://www.sqlite.org/compile.html).

Comment: I don't believe this is the case. I can run the query just fine in sqlite3 as I showed above. It's only in gorm I run into the issue.

Comment: You've probably built your sqlite3 client with this flag, but gorm uses `github.com/mattn/go-sqlite3` driver which comes with its own sqlite3 client: https://github.com/mattn/go-sqlite3/blob/master/sqlite3-binding.c