# Deleting only 1 record in SQLite Gorm

Tags: go, go-gorm

I am trying to achieve the following thing:

I have a table with multiple imageIds (can be duplicates) too and I wish to delete only the first occurrence of record with the mentioned `imageId`

For example, consider the following schema:

| Name | ImageId |
| --- | --- |
| Bob | 1 |
| Bob | 1 |
| Bob | 2 |

After firing the query, the result should be as follows:

| Name | ImageId |
| --- | --- |
| Bob | 1 |
| Bob | 2 |

I am using the following query but this deletes all the instances with imageId 1:

Query:

```
DB.Where(&models.Cart{BuyerEmailId: data.BuyerEmailId, ImageId: data.ImageId}).Limit(1).Delete(&dataToBeDeletedFromCart)
```

Result:

| Name | ImageId |
| --- | --- |
| Bob | 2 |

Is my syntax wrong for deleting from the table in SQLite? I am using gorm v 1.22. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

did you check the answer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31038805/how-to-delete-range-of-items-from-database-with-gorm) :

> Looks like it's a problem of sqlite3 driver. Please check this thread:
> How do you enable LIMIT for DELETE in SQLite?
>
> You need to pass flag SQLITE_ENABLE_UPDATE_DELETE_LIMIT to this driver
> somehow. Unfortunately, I have no idea how, because the driver uses
> "amalgamation" of SQLite source code and documentation says that you
> cannot use SQLITE_ENABLE_UPDATE_DELETE_LIMIT with it
> (https://www.sqlite.org/compile.html).