# How to erase only ONE line from a DataGridView and a SQLite database when button is clicked?

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I'm working on a Restaurant application composed by two Forms, Form1 and Form2.

Form2 has a couple of textBoxes, a DataGridView and a button called "add product".

When the "add product" button is clicked, the data entered in the textboxes above is "moved" into the dataGridView and a new dynamic column appears with an "erase" button for each row. If the user clicks the "erase" button the row is erased from the dataGridView.

What I'm trying to do, is to erase THAT row information from my database too. With the code I'm posting I get to erase that row but I'm also erasing some other ones with the same specifications, which I don't want to.

This are the class attributes:

```
    double precio = 0;
    double cantidad = 0;
    double subtotal = 0;
    double total = 0;

    // THIS CODE ADDS A NEW ROW TO THE DATAGRIDVIEW AND TO THE DATABASE
private void btnAgregarItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Pagos.Rows.Add(txtID.Text, txtNombre.Text, txtPrecio.Text, txtCantidad.Text, etiquetaSubTotalNum.Text);

            int id_producto = Convert.ToInt32(txtID.Text.ToString());
            string nombre = txtNombre.Text.ToString();
            double precio = Convert.ToDouble(txtPrecio.Text.ToString());
            double cantidad = Convert.ToDouble(txtCantidad.Text.ToString());
            double subtotal = Convert.ToDouble(etiquetaSubTotalNum.Text.ToString());

            String consulta = "INSERT INTO Productos (id_producto, nombre, precio, cantidad, subtotal) VALUES(@id_producto, @nombre, @precio, @cantidad, @subtotal)";
            SQLiteCommand cmd = new SQLiteCommand(consulta, conexion);

            cmd.Parameters.Clear();
            cmd.Parameters.Add(new SQLiteParameter("@id_producto", id_producto));
            cmd.Parameters.Add(new SQLiteParameter("@nombre", nombre));
            cmd.Parameters.Add(new SQLiteParameter("@precio", precio));
            cmd.Parameters.Add(new SQLiteParameter("@cantidad", cantidad));
            cmd.Parameters.Add(new SQLiteParameter("@subtotal", subtotal));
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

    }


      // THIS CODE ERASES THE CURRENT ROW FROM THE DATAGRIDVIEW, BUT IT´S POSSIBLE THAT IT ALSO ERASES MORE THAN ONE LINE FROM THE DATABASE 

private void Pagos_CellClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
        if (this.Pagos.Columns[e.ColumnIndex].Name == "colBotones")
        {
            Pagos.Rows.RemoveAt(Pagos.CurrentRow.Index);

            int id_producto = Convert.ToInt32(txtID.Text.ToString());
            string nombre = txtNombre.Text.ToString();
            double precio = Convert.ToDouble(txtPrecio.Text.ToString());
            double cantidad = Convert.ToDouble(txtCantidad.Text.ToString());
            double subtotal = Convert.ToDouble(etiquetaSubTotalNum.Text.ToString());

            String consulta = "DELETE FROM Productos where id_producto = @id_producto and nombre = @nombre and precio = @precio and cantidad = @cantidad and subtotal =  @subtotal";
            SQLiteCommand cmd = new SQLiteCommand(consulta, conexion);

            cmd.Parameters.Clear();
            cmd.Parameters.Add(new SQLiteParameter("@id_producto", id_producto));
            cmd.Parameters.Add(new SQLiteParameter("@nombre", nombre));
            cmd.Parameters.Add(new SQLiteParameter("@precio", precio));
            cmd.Parameters.Add(new SQLiteParameter("@cantidad", cantidad));
            cmd.Parameters.Add(new SQLiteParameter("@subtotal", subtotal));
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
    }
```

Comment: if you have multiple rows that meet the sames specifications that your statement is specifying then you need another column that keeps this unique. I'm unsure why in your Productos table you have multiple rows that meet all these values so there is no way to be more specific to your issue.

Comment: That´s exactly what is wrong with the code, I can have mutiple rows with the same specifications and with these they will be all erased, wich would be wrong. I need the code to erase the row from the dataGridView AND from my DB at the same time, every time the "erase" button is clicked on the dataGridView row!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you enable LIMIT for DELETE in SQLite?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1824490/how-do-you-enable-limit-for-delete-in-sqlite)