# Flutter SQLITE how to delete with limit

Tags: sqlite, flutter, dart

In my database I have several times the same value which returns, I want to delete the most recent value but when I want to perform a LIMIT I have an error.

My databaseHelper :

```
class DatabaseHelper{

  static final _dbName = AppConfig.DATABASE_NAME;
  static final _dbVersion = AppConfig.DATABASE_VERSION;
  static final tableName = 'counter';

  static final columnId = '_id';
  static final columnType = 'type';
  static final columnStatus = 'status';

  DatabaseHelper._privateConstructor();
  static final DatabaseHelper instance = DatabaseHelper._privateConstructor();

  static Database _database;
  Future<Database> get database async{
    if(_database != null) return _database;
    _database = await _initiateDatabase();
    return _database;
  }

  _initiateDatabase() async{
    return await openDatabase(join(await getDatabasesPath(), _dbName), version: _dbVersion, onCreate: _onCreate);
  }

  Future _onCreate(Database db, int version) async{
    await db.execute(''' 
      CREATE TABLE $tableName (
        $columnId ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
        $columnType TEXT NOT NULL,
        $columnStatus TEXT NOT NULL
      )
      '''
    );
  }

  Future<int> insert(Map<String, dynamic> row) async
  {
    Database db = await instance.database;
    return await db.insert(tableName, row);
  }

  Future<List<Map<String, dynamic>>> queryAll() async
  {
    Database _db = await instance.database;
    return await _db.query(tableName);
  }

  Future<int> delete(int id) async
  {
    Database _db = await instance.database;
    return await _db.delete(tableName, where: '$columnId = ?', whereArgs: [id]);
  }

  Future<void> deleteAll() async
  {
    Database _db = await instance.database;
    return await _db.delete(tableName);
  }


  // Here is my problem
  Future<int> deletePersonnel(String type) async
  {
    Database _db = await instance.database;
    return await _db.rawDelete("DELETE FROM $tableName WHERE $columnType = $type LIMIT 1");
  }
}
```

In my deletePersonnel function, The request works if I write this :

```
wait _db.rawDelete("DELETE FROM $tableName");
```

But I have an error if I write this :

```
wait _db.rawDelete("DELETE FROM $tableName WHERE $columnType = $type LIMIT 1");
```

Here is an exemple of the value in my database:

```
[
{type: Test, status: High}, 
{type: Test, status: High}, 
{type: Active, status: Low}, 
{type: Test, status: High}
]
```

As you can see I have several times the same values ​​which appear in my database, so I want to delete a value which corresponds to my type by deleting the last entry

The error that I have :

```
E/SQLiteLog(10576): (1) near "LIMIT": syntax error
```

BUT if I remove the LIMIT 1 in my request I have an error too :

```
no such column: Test
```

Comment: show us your definition for $tableName and $columnType and $type.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1824490/how-do-you-enable-limit-for-delete-in-sqlite
take a look this question if it might help