# Limit number of items to be deleted sqlite python

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlite, sql-delete

I am trying to limit the amount of items being deleted with sqlite and python using this code as there are multiple entries with the same value but I receive `sqlite3.OperationalError: near "LIMIT": syntax error` Any help will be appreciated!

My Code:

```
delete = 'DELETE from Items WHERE ( ItemNumber = ' + str(request.form['number']) + ' AND PhoneNumber = ' + str(session['phonenumber']) + ' LIMIT 1)'
```

Comment: Specifically [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12673999/565635) from the duplicate question should help you.

Comment: When trying 'DELETE FROM Items WHERE ItemNumber = (SELECT * FROM Items WHERE ItemNumber = ' + str(request.form['number']) + ' AND PhoneNumber = ' + str(session['phonenumber']) + ' limit 1)' I receive the error sqlite3.OperationalError: only a single result allowed for a SELECT that is part of an expression

Comment: That's because you didn't follow the instructions of the answer exactly. Try again and pay attention (don't use `SELECT *`).