# How to turn ON Features Normally Turned Off in Sqlite3?

Tags: sqlite, sql-update, sql-limit

I am trying to use Limit feature with Update in Sqlite3 but I need to turn ON that feature as is it said [HERE](https://sqlite.org/compile.html#enable_update_delete_limit)

SQLITE_ENABLE_UPDATE_DELETE_LIMIT

How Can I turn it ON?

Comment: You need to fetch the source code, modify the makefile, and recompile the library.

Comment: The steps are [described in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1824557/9952196). Use the current version, of course, not the ancient one in that example.