# SQLite3 LIMIT for UPDATE and DELETE on PHP in Windows?

Tags: php, windows, sqlite

I have learned that SQLite3 does not support LIMIT in UPDATE or DELETE queries by default. To enable this I understand we need to recompile the SQLite library as mentioned in this thread [How do you enable LIMIT for DELETE in SQLite?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1824490/how-do-you-enable-limit-for-delete-in-sqlite).

But PHP for Windows doesn't seem to use any library but php_sqlite3.dll.

So how do we enable SQLITE_ENABLE_UPDATE_DELETE_LIMIT in PHP on Windows?

Comment: You have to compile your own custom dll using the appropriately-created sqlite3.c and arrange for that to be loaded instead of the default one.

Comment: Oh that sucks. Thank you for replying